# How should dependencies between modules be declared in a maven multi-module project?

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

Assume I have a maven multi-module project consisting of parent `P` and its modules `A` and `B`. How should a dependency of `B` to `A` be declared?

Until today I always used the following in `B`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But a colleague just mentioned that it is also possible to create a dependency management entry for  `A` in parent `P`

```
<depednencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and then `B` only needs to specify:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there any downside to either of those methods? Does maven intend one to be actually used? Or is there actually another style I'm missing?

In the project I'm working all modules have the same version and we are having much more than 3 modules and also some deeper nesting than only 2 levels. Does this have an influence on which declaration style should be preferred?

Comment: In the end is does not really matter which style you use...just use it consistently...I prefer to use the one with using the version via `${project.version}` and not using dependencyManagement it shows easier which dependency is from within the project (in particular in larger multi module builds) identified by the `<version>${project.version}</version>`...